# if-clause+present continuous

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions, present-continuous

I've read this [topic about if-clause](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv315.shtml) and it seems sanely to ask what is the point of if-clause + present continuous. I interest in the following case:

> When **they are speaking**, they do something.

and

> If **they are speaking**, they do something.

Does the latter sentence make a sense at all? If it is true, what are the differences between these sentences?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. The present continuous construction doesn't 'mean' anything different in a *when* clause or an *if* clause than it does anywhere else: it marks the action as continuous through the time spoken of.

Comment: The lack of logical causation between `speaking` and `doing something` makes these sentences a bit nonsensical; they seem perfectly fine to me, they just don't really mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real semantic difference that an everyday speaker would pick up on.

Both sentences make sense, but because you've used the pro-verb *do* in them, it will probably sound weird to most readers.

> ***When*** I open my mouth, a fool starts to speak
>   ***If*** I open my mouth, a fool starts to speak

I'm sure that a semantician can do a better job of eliciting differences, but for the purposes of conversation, you can consider these equivalent and sensical.

---

<sub>The difference becomes clearer if you use *then* as a conjunction, since it becomes a temporal and logical relationship, respectively. However that's a tangent to your question.</sub>